# How to create a cummulative sum of each column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have been having some trouble trying to solve this issue. I have a dataframe 4 variables:

```
rr_1 rr_2 cc_1 cc_2
 100    0     1    0
 200  100     1    1
 300  300     1    1
 400  500     1    1
   0    0     0    0
```

My cc variables have a value of 1 everytime the corresponding rr variables have a value that is higher than 0. What I am trying to accomplish is to create a cummulative series for the cc variables such that the ending result should look like this:

```
rr_1 rr_2 cc_1 cc_2
 100    0     1    0
 200  100     2    1
 300  300     3    2
 400  500     4    3
   0    0     4    3
```

I have tried several things to solve this issue.

(1) I have created a function such as:

```
df <- df1 %>% select(starts_with("cc"))
rows <- nrow(df) 

cc_cum <- function(x) {
        for(i in 2:rows) {
          df$x[i] <- df$x[i-1] + df$x[i]
        }

apply(df, 2, cc_cum)
```

(2) I have created vectors:

```
df <- df1 %>% select(starts_with("cc"))

cc_cum <- function(x) {
          x <- as.vector(df$x)
          x <- cumsum(x)
          df$x <- x
}

apply(df, 2, cc_cum )
```

(3) I have also tried:

```
df <- df1 %>% select(starts_with("cc"))
rows <- nrow(df) 

cc_cum <- function(x) {
             for(i in 2:rows) {
                 df$x[i] <- df$x[i-1] + df$x[i]
             }
          }

apply(df, 2, cc_cum)
```

The weird thing is that all of the solutions that I have tried above work for each single column if I remove them from the function and the apply. For instance, this code works

```
df <- df1 %>% select(starts_with("cc"))

rows <- nrow(df) 

for(i in 2:rows) {
  df$cc_1[i] <- df$cc_1[i-1] + df$cc_1[i]
}
```

However, this code is to be used for a larger dataset that will have multiple cc levels and therefore I cannot predict how many there will be so I cant really code all of the possibilities of cc.

Any feedback on this will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the in-built `cumsum` function for multiple columns with `lapply`

```
cols <- grep("^cc", names(df))
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], cumsum)

df
#   rr_1 rr_2 cc_1 cc_2
#1  100    0    1    0
#2  200  100    2    1
#3  300  300    3    2
#4  400  500    4    3
#5    0    0    4    3
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we can use `mutate_at` to select specific columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("cc")), cumsum)
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you. It was so simple and I think I was overcomplicating it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), get the names of the data.frame that `startsQWith` 'cc', specify the `.SDcols`, loop through the `.SD`, get the `cumsum` and assign (`:=`) the output back to the columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(df1)[startsWith(names(df1), "cc")]
setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols = nm1]
df1
#   rr_1 rr_2 cc_1 cc_2
#1:  100    0    1    0
#2:  200  100    2    1
#3:  300  300    3    2
#4:  400  500    4    3
#5:    0    0    4    3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(rr_1 = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 0L), rr_2 = c(0L, 
100L, 300L, 500L, 0L), cc_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), cc_2 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <-data.frame("rr_1" = c(100,200,300,400,0), "rr_2" = c(0,100,300,500,0), "cc_1" = c(1,1,1,1,0),"cc_2"=c(0,1,1,1,0))

> df
  rr_1 rr_2 cc_1 cc_2
1  100    0    1    0
2  200  100    1    1
3  300  300    1    1
4  400  500    1    1
5    0    0    0    0

csum <- function(x) cumsum(x)

new_data <- data.frame(df[c("rr_1","rr_2")],sapply(df[c("cc_1","cc_2")],csum))

> new_data
  rr_1 rr_2 cc_1 cc_2
1  100    0    1    0
2  200  100    2    1
3  300  300    3    2
4  400  500    4    3
5    0    0    4    3
```